# Laravel: How to use controller public function for master layout

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel and I would need some help.. what I am trying to do is:
I have a @foreach in my master layout and I would like to display it on all views that is like a "header" the problem is I don't know where to set that variable for the foreach

My example master layout (app.blade.php):

```
@foreach($livedrops as $item)
               <div class="livedrops-item animated fadeIn"  game-id="{{ $item->id }}">
                   <div class="row" style="margin-left: -5px; margin-right: -5px;">
                       <div class="col-12 livedrops-item-nickname">
                           <img class="livedrops-item-avatar" src="{{ $item->avatar }}">
                           <span class="livedrops-item-player">{{ $item->player }}

                  </span>
                       </div>
                   </div>

                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-12 text-center game">
                           <img class="img-fluid livedrop-img livedrops-game-image" src="{{ $item->gameimage }}">

                   <div class="row livedrop-row">
                       <div class="col-12 livedrops-game-price text-left"> <i class="fas fa-money-bill livedrop-bill"></i>{{ $item->gameprice }}  MDL</div>
                   </div>

                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
     @endforeach
```

My controller example:

```
private function fetch() {

      $livedrops = DB::table('case_history')
                  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'case_history.player')
                  ->join('cases', 'cases.id', '=', 'case_history.case_id')
                  ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'case_history.player')
                  ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'case_history.won_game')
                  ->select('case_history.id as id', 'users.name as player', 'users.premium as vip', 'profiles.avatar as avatar', 'cases.price as price', 'products.name as game', 'products.price as gameprice', 'products.image as gameimage', 'products.color as color')
                  ->orderBy('case_history.id', 'desc')
                  ->limit(15)
                  ->get();

        return $livedrops;
    }
```

Comment: I think a View Composer is what you are looking for. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the AppServiceProvider. In your boot method you can add:

```
config(['livedrops' => DB::table('case_history')
              ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'case_history.player')
              ->join('cases', 'cases.id', '=', 'case_history.case_id')
              ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'case_history.player')
              ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'case_history.won_game')
              ->select('case_history.id as id', 'users.name as player', 'users.premium as vip', 'profiles.avatar as avatar', 'cases.price as price', 'products.name as game', 'products.price as gameprice', 'products.image as gameimage', 'products.color as color')
              ->orderBy('case_history.id', 'desc')
              ->limit(15)
              ->get()]);
```

In your view jusz change your foreach in

```
@foreach(config('livedrops') as $item)
```

Comment: Hey I tried it and I get this: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: that would mean your Query doesn't return a proper collection. Did you put the code in the boot method of your AppServiceProvider?
What do you get if you add dd(config('livedrops'); in your AppServiceProvider after the declaration?

Comment: hey worked thank you! I never worked with appserviceprovider so I've created a new provider instead of adding my code in the boot from appserviceprovider..

Answer (score 1):

Generate helper file and make function in that file you can use it anywhere.
Because of your app.blade.php file will call in every file so.

Create a `helpers.php` file in your app folder and load it up with composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php" // <---- ADD THIS
    ]
},
```

After adding that to your `composer.json` file, run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

add helpers.php file under app folder.

**helpers.php** file

```
<?php
 function fetch() {

      $livedrops = DB::table('case_history')
                  ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'case_history.player')
                  ->join('cases', 'cases.id', '=', 'case_history.case_id')
                  ->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'case_history.player')
                  ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'case_history.won_game')
                  ->select('case_history.id as id', 'users.name as player', 'users.premium as vip', 'profiles.avatar as avatar', 'cases.price as price', 'products.name as game', 'products.price as gameprice', 'products.image as gameimage', 'products.color as color')
                  ->orderBy('case_history.id', 'desc')
                  ->limit(15)
                  ->get();

        return $livedrops;
    }
?>
```

**App.blade.php** file

```
@php
$livedrops = fetch();
@endphp

@foreach($livedrops as $item)
@endforeach
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\newlootodds\app\help
ers.php on line 2

Comment: forgot to remove public from function. can you public from helper?